# One-liner to extract domain from email address

Tags: regex, string, scala, email, pattern-matching

How to optionally extract `domain` from `local-part@domain`? My attempt is

```
Try(email.split("@")(1)).toOption
```

but seems there should be a way without depending on exception handling. Ideally, I am after one-liner.

Comment: "shortest one liner" and "cleaner way" are not often the same thing. I voted to close because it seems mainly opinion based among the myriad of scala ways to do it and not something where there can be an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not one liner, and only works on **2.13**. But this seems very clear to me.

```
def extractDomain(email: String): Option[String] = email match {
  case s"${_}@${domain}" => Some(domain)
  case _ => None
}
```

*(Note, if there are more than one `@` sign, this will just split on the first one)*.

Answer (score 3):

```
email.dropWhile(_ != '@').drop(1)
```

Comment: this returns an empty string if there's no `@`, but what the OP wants is to have `None` in this case

Answer (score 2):

```
email.split("@").lastOption
```

These are equivalent ONLY if what's passed is an email address.

If the string passed doesn't include `@` then `lastOption` will still return a `Some()` of the entire string, whereas your solution will return a `None`.

So if you can trust your input then this answer provides a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Some(email.split("@")(1))`, this will split the `String` and then wrap in `Some`, which is instance of `Option`.

Comment: This will throw if `@` is missing, for example, `Some("foobar.com".split("@")(1))`.

Comment: @MarioGalic and what do you expect in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Let me cheat a little: I will prepare separate file `Email.scala` with extractor:

```
object Email{
  def unapply(mail: String): Option[(String, String)] = {
        mail match {
        case s"$user@$domain" => Some(user, domain)
        case _ => None
      }
  }
}
```

and then it can be used with pattern matching:

```
val Email(_, domain) = "test@domain.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a one-liner, but I always `match` on array extractors when I do `String.split` (pre-2.13), I think it's short enough and reads much better than getting parts by index.

```scala
email.split("@", 2) match {
  case Array(_, domainPart @ _*) => domainPart.headOption
}
```

`limit = 2` makes sure that `domainPart` has at most 1 element.

Note you don't need a catch-all in this case, since `split` will always return at least one value in the array (although makes sense to cover it with tests to protect against future changes).